# Darknet training stops in between of the training at random epoch

Tags: python, windows, deep-learning, darknet

**brief:**

```
 system: windows 10

 Cuda: 11.5

 Darknet version: latest

 visual studio: 2019
```

I am a training model with "https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet"

my command to start training is:

[cammand img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOeVU.png)

training stops for no reason or errors it stops at any iteration randomly

[output img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDlwv.png)

**What I have tried:**

1. restart the training and system both
2. rebuild the darknet from scratch
3. disable windows security and real-time protection
4. update windows

> any suggestion is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by looking into the following steps, This step is suggested by the "https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet" :

If you have an issue with training - no-detections / Nan avg-loss / low accuracy:

1. read FAQ: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/wiki/FAQ---frequently-asked-
   questions
2. Check if command is correct
3. Dataset is correct or not, means bounding boxes and classes index
4. check your dataset - run training with flag `-show_imgs` i.e. `./darknet detector  train ... -show_imgs` and look at the `aug_...jpg` images, do you see correct
   truth bounded boxes?
5. Check cfg-file it has correct values
   **6. check `bad.list` and `bad_label.list` for error, if they exist.**
6. Read `How to train (to detect your custom objects)` and `How to improve object  detection` in the Readme:
   "https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/README.md"

Mine was solved by the 6th step which is highlighted, In that file, I have seen two issues in each one of them:

Issue 1: "train.txt" contains the file which is deleted by myself for the wrong
annotation like "0 0 0 0 0"

Issue 2: I have only 1 class as output prediction but one of the text files contain
class index 15 so I removed the 15 and place 0 to each place and save the
file.

`bad.list` and `bad_label.list` those files will give you also the error and file name by which the error has occurred.

tips: Do check `bad.list` and `bad_label.list` even if you dont get error on display it will tell you the hidden errors

thanks
have fun
and Make amazing things